# Java rectangle collision detection confusion

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

I have made a simple 2D state change game using Bucky's slick Java tutorials, I modified this game and now want to set collisions on the map so that my player can not go through the house on the map. I think I kind of have a idea of how collisions work:

you make 2 rectangles using the following code:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
 return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

}

1 for the player and 1 for the obstacle, how would I put this into my code and how would I tell java that the rectangle for the obstacle is different to the player rectangle?

Then after making the 2 rectangles I would set up a if statement saying something like if intersects do this...

Hopefully after this I think it would work. Some more information on the game, it being a state change game it has a few methods, methods like init, render and update (where do I place my rectangles and if statements, in the update method?) also, its a overhead view game kind of like pokemon if that helps. If you require my code please ask, I did not want to put it on now to overcrowd this post.

Edit1:

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{

    Animation bucky, movingUp, movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight, movingBL, movingBR, movingFL, movingFR;
    Image worldMap;
    boolean quit = false;//gives user to quit the game
    int[] duration = {200, 200};//how long frame stays up for
    float buckyPositionX = 0;
    float buckyPositionY = 0;
    float shiftX = buckyPositionX + 320;//keeps user in the middle of the screem
    float shiftY = buckyPositionY + 160;//the numbers are half of the screen size

    public Play(int state){
    }   
    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException{
          worldMap = new Image("res/world.png");
          Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/b.png"), new Image("res/b.png")}; //these are the images to be used in the "walkUp" animation
          Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/f.png"), new Image("res/f.png")};
          Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/l.png"), new Image("res/l.png")};
          Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/r.png"), new Image("res/r.png")};
          Image[] walkBL = {new Image("res/bl.png"), new Image("res/bl.png")};
          Image[] walkBR = {new Image("res/br.png"), new Image("res/br.png")};
          Image[] walkFL = {new Image("res/fl.png"), new Image("res/fl.png")};
          Image[] walkFR = {new Image("res/fr.png"), new Image("res/fr.png")};

    movingUp = new Animation(walkUp, duration, false);
    movingDown = new Animation(walkDown, duration, false);  
    movingLeft = new Animation(walkLeft, duration, false);  
    movingRight = new Animation(walkRight, duration, false);
    movingBL = new Animation(walkBL, duration, false);
    movingBR = new Animation(walkBR, duration, false);
    movingFL = new Animation(walkFL, duration, false);
    movingFR = new Animation(walkFR, duration, false);
    bucky = movingDown;//facing screen initially on startup
    }


    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    worldMap.draw(buckyPositionX, buckyPositionY);//position 0,0
    bucky.draw(shiftX, shiftY);//makes him appear at center of map
    g.drawString("Suraj's X: "+buckyPositionX+"\nSuraj's Y: "+buckyPositionY,400,20);//tells us the position

    if(quit==true){
        g.drawString("Resume(R)", 250, 100);
        g.drawString("Main(M)", 250, 150);
        g.drawString("Quit Game(Q)", 250, 200);
        if(quit==false){
            g.clear();//wipe off everything from screen
        }
    }
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //up
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        bucky = movingUp;//changes the image to his back
        buckyPositionY += 10;;//increase the Y coordinates of bucky (move him up)
        if(buckyPositionY>162){//if I reach the top 
            buckyPositionY -= 10;//stops any further movement in that direction
        }
    }

    //down
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        bucky = movingDown;
        buckyPositionY -= 10;
        if(buckyPositionY<-600){
            buckyPositionY += 10;//basically change the direction if + make -
    }}
    //left
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
        bucky = movingLeft;
        buckyPositionX += 10;
        if(buckyPositionX>324){
            buckyPositionX -= 10;//delta * .1f
    }}
    //right
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
        bucky = movingRight;
        buckyPositionX -= 10;
        if(buckyPositionX<-840){
            buckyPositionX += 10;
    }}




    //2 key combos start here
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT) && input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        bucky = movingBR;
        buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        if(buckyPositionX<-840){
            buckyPositionX += delta * .1f;
            if(buckyPositionY>162){
                buckyPositionY -= delta * .1f;
            }}}
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT) && input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){
        bucky = movingBL;
        buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        if(buckyPositionX>324){
            buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
            if(buckyPositionY>162){
                buckyPositionY -= delta * .1f;
            }}}
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT) && input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        bucky = movingFR;
        buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        if(buckyPositionY<-600){
            buckyPositionY += delta * .1f;
            if(buckyPositionX<-840){
                buckyPositionX += delta * .1f;
            }}}
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT) && input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
        bucky = movingFL;
        buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
        if(buckyPositionY<-600){
            buckyPositionY += delta * .1f;
            if(buckyPositionX>324){
                buckyPositionX -= delta * .1f;
            }}}

     //escape
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)){
        quit=true;
    }
    //when the menu is up
    if(quit==true){//is the menu on the screen
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_R)){
            quit = false;//resumes the game, makes menu dissapear
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M)){
            sbg.enterState(0);//takes you to the main menu
        }
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q)){
            System.exit(0);//quits the game
        }
    }

}

    public int getID(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is my Play class, the only other 2 class's I have are the main and the menu, I cant imagine the rectangle methods being made in the main or menu class so the only one left is the Play, but I dont understand how to make 2 different Rectangles (one for the player the other for the house) in the code I have done so far. If you require my main and my menu class please tell me.

Edit 3:

I have tried what you have said and made a Rectanglebase class and put the if sattement you had posted inside there but am getting errors, it is asking me to make a method for getX and getY in my player class also the public in fornt of the constructor also has a error:

```
public Rectanglebase{}//the public is saying syntax error
```

I also made a Home and Player class like you had said but am a bit confused on what I need to put in it, I put under the Home class:

```
return Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
```

but am getting errors, I am not sure if I did this correct or not.
Also, in the player class for the x,y positions how would I set my float variables from my Play class for my player?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of a *Game Loop* / *Game Logic* and *collision detection* via `Rectangle2D#intersects(..)` method .

It uses `JPanel` to draw everything on and `Rectangle2D` is used for `Entity` class (which is any object needed to be drawn to `GamePanel` which is our JPanel where everything is drawn).

The `updateGame()` method is where you will find the collision checking:

```
    private void updateGame() {

        if (entities.get(0).intersects(entities.get(1))) {
            System.out.println("Intersecting");
        }
         ....
    }
```

You are *Player 1* and move with <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>. When you intersect *Player 2*, a `println()` will confirm the intersection.

[image]

GameLogic.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author David Kroukamp
 */
public class GameLogic {

    public GameLogic() {
        initComponents();
    }
    final GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(500, 500);

    private void initComponents() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Entity entity1 = new Entity(100, 100, 100, 100, createWhiteImage());
        Entity entity2 = new Entity(300, 200, 100, 100, createBlackImage());

        gp.addEntity(entity1);
        gp.addEntity(entity2);//just a standing still JPanel

        setGamePanelKeyBindings(gp, entity1);

        frame.add(gp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //start the game loop which will repaint the screen
        runGameLoop();
    }
    //Starts a new thread and runs the game loop in it.

    public void runGameLoop() {
        Thread loop = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gp.running.set(true);
                gp.gameLoop();
            }
        });
        loop.start();
    }

    private void setGamePanelKeyBindings(GamePanel gp, final Entity entity) {
        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "D pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("D pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.RIGHT = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "A pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("A pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.LEFT = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "W pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("W pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.UP = true;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "S pressed");
        gp.getActionMap().put("S pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.DOWN = true;
            }
        });
        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "D released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("D released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.RIGHT = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "A released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("A released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.LEFT = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "W released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("W released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.UP = false;
            }
        });

        gp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "S released");
        gp.getActionMap().put("S released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                entity.DOWN = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameLogic();
            }
        });
    }

    private BufferedImage createWhiteImage() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        return img;
    }

    private BufferedImage createBlackImage() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        return img;
    }
}

class Entity extends Rectangle2D.Double {

    private int speed = 5;
    public boolean UP = false,
            DOWN = false,
            LEFT = false,
            RIGHT = false;
    private final BufferedImage image;

    public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height, BufferedImage image) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (UP) {
            y -= speed;
        }
        if (DOWN) {
            y += speed;
        }
        if (LEFT) {
            x -= speed;
        }
        if (RIGHT) {
            x += speed;
        }

    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private int width, height;
    private int frameCount = 0;
    private int fps = 0;
    public static AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false), paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    final ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    GamePanel(int w, int h) {
        super(true);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);//mustnt repaint itself the gameloop will do that
        setLayout(null);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity e) {
        entities.add(e);
    }

    //Only run this in another Thread!
    public void gameLoop() {
        //This value would probably be stored elsewhere.
        final double GAME_HERTZ = 30.0;
        //Calculate how many ns each frame should take for our target game hertz.
        final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
        //At the very most we will update the game this many times before a new render.
        //If you're worried about visual hitches more than perfect timing, set this to 1.
        final int MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER = 5;
        //We will need the last update time.
        double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Store the last time we rendered.
        double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

        //If we are able to get as high as this FPS, don't render again.
        final double TARGET_FPS = 60;
        final double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

        //Simple way of finding FPS.
        int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

        while (running.get()) {
            double now = System.nanoTime();
            int updateCount = 0;

            if (!paused.get()) {
                //Do as many game updates as we need to, potentially playing catchup.
                while (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER) {
                    updateGame();
                    lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                    updateCount++;
                }

                //If for some reason an update takes forever, we don't want to do an insane number of catchups.
                //If you were doing some sort of game that needed to keep EXACT time, you would get rid of this.
                if (now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                }

                drawGame();
                lastRenderTime = now;

                //Update the frames we got.
                int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

                if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime) {
                    System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount);
                    fps = frameCount;
                    frameCount = 0;
                    lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
                }

                //Yield until it has been at least the target time between renders. This saves the CPU from hogging.
                while (now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) {
                    //allow the threading system to play threads that are waiting to run.
                    Thread.yield();

                    //This stops the app from consuming all your CPU. It makes this slightly less accurate, but is worth it.
                    //You can remove this line and it will still work (better), your CPU just climbs on certain OSes.
                    //FYI on some OS's this can cause pretty bad stuttering. Scroll down and have a look at different peoples' solutions to this.
                    //On my OS it does not unpuase the game if i take this away
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    now = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawGame() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateGame() {

        if (entities.get(0).intersects(entities.get(1))) {
            System.out.println("Intersecting");
        }

        for (Entity e : entities) {
            e.move();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;

        applyRenderHints(g2d);

        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (Entity e : entities) {
            g2d.drawImage(e.getImage(), (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY(), null);
        }

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 5, 10);

        frameCount++;
    }
    private final static RenderingHints textRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private final static RenderingHints imageRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private final static RenderingHints colorRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    private final static RenderingHints interpolationRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    private final static RenderingHints renderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    public static void applyRenderHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setRenderingHints(textRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(imageRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(colorRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(interpolationRenderHints);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(renderHints);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for key bindings; also consider `Shape#intersects()` in `Entity`.

Comment: @trashgod +1 thank you for advice, updated code to use `Rectangle2D#intersects` instead of `JPanel` (as it was sky rocketing the repaints when moved). I didnt use `Shape` as those overridden methods where confusing me pathIterator etc :O)

Comment: Excellent! `Rectangle2D#intersects` may be more efficient if one doesn't need the full generality of the (typical) `Shape` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`if(house.getBounds().contains(player.getX(),player.getY()){//do something}`

as long as your house and your player rectangles are defined in different classes, java will be able to tell the difference

create a class first that is a base class for dealing with rectangles:

```
public class Rectanglebase{

public void getBounds(){//write method}

//write other methods you will need to use for both rectangles here

public Rectanglebase{//default constructor}

}//end class definition
```

now write classes for the house and player:

```
public class House extends Rectanglebase{
//getBounds() is inherited, so just write stuff to do with the graphics of the house here
}
```

when you generate the house in your main code, you can make your own:

`House house = new House();`

then generate the class for the player in a similar way, then construct in in your main code:

`Player player = new Player()`

`house` and `player` are different variables, this is how java will tell the difference between your house and player

Comment: I understand the if statement now, thank you for posting it but what I dont understand is how to set up my rectangles, heres my code: (sorry it will be on the next post)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I added a new answer as I couldn't fit my question in this small box just in case you cant find it, it is towards the top of the page.