# Flickering images in java, BufferStrategy?

Tags: java, image, swing, flicker

I'm making a game in java and need to paint units on a gameboard. I put all units in a list and paints every unit in that list. The paint method looks like this:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        if (unitList != null) {
            Collections.sort(unitList);
            for (Unit unit : unitList) {
                Image image = unit.getImage();
                g.drawImage(
                        image,
                        (int) (playPosition.x + unit.getPosition().getX() - image
                                .getWidth(null) / 2), (int) (playPosition.y
                                + unit.getPosition().getY() - image
                                .getHeight(null) / 2), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to make a BufferStrategy but it only makes the problem worse, guess I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Override paintComponent() not paint()

Comment: maybe caused by `Collections.sort(unitList);`, nobody knows, prepare that before and to use `paintComponent`,

Comment: @user1900750 this question isn't answerable, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: As said by mKorbel its hard to answer the question, but have a look at an anwser o mine demontsrating some gameloop/logic in java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825515/java-rectangle-collision-detection-confusion/13827649#13827649

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: Do not sort, use a SortedSet like TreeSet. That also has less concurrency problems and changes less. In an applet better use ImageIO.read or getResource instead of asynchrone reading with partial images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't implemented `BufferStrategy` correctly.
Try manual double buffering by doing offscreen painting on an `Image`, and then just paint the whole said image in your regular overriden `paint()` method.

You would do that like so:

```
// Double buffering objects.
Image doubleBufferImage;
Graphics doubleBufferGraphics;

/*
 * Onscreen rendering.
 */
 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     doubleBufferImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
     doubleBufferGraphics = doubleBufferImage.getGraphics();
     paintStuff(doubleBufferGraphics);
     g.drawImage(doubleBufferImage, 0, 0, this);
 }

/*
 * Offscreen rendering.
 */
 public void paintStuff(Graphics g) {
     if (unitList != null) {
        Collections.sort(unitList);
        for (Unit unit : unitList) {
            Image image = unit.getImage();
            g.drawImage(
                    image,
                    (int) (playPosition.x + unit.getPosition().getX() - image
                            .getWidth(null) / 2), (int) (playPosition.y
                            + unit.getPosition().getY() - image
                            .getHeight(null) / 2), null);
        }
    }
 }
```