# KeyAdapter doesn't work in JPanel class but works in JFrame class

Tags: java, swing

**Background**
I am building a game library to make game development faster, and so far it is going fairly smoothly.

I have the following:

- Main entry class `public static void main(String[] args)`

  - this class then initiates a class from my library called `Game`
  - then sets the window size and adds a `Room` to the `JFrame`
- When an extendable `Room` (Room is a game level) class is created it it starts a thread from the room to draw all the objects added to it.

  - Objects can have events added to them (the part I am stuck on)

So above is what the main idea entails.

Here is the entry class (very simple).

```
package test;

import JGame.Game.Game;
import JGame.Room.Room;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import test.Rooms.Room1;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game("Test Game"); // This sets the window title
        game.start(800, 600); // This sets the size of the window

        Room room1 = new Room1();
        game.setRoom(room1);  // adds the JPanel to the main frame
    }
}
```

`Room1` extends `Room`. Within `Room1` all of the game object that are associated with that room are added to it.

```
public class Room extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    ArrayList<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                this.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
    public void addGameObjectAt(GameObject gameObject, int x, int y){
        // Sets private variables in GameObject
        // These are then grabbed in the paintComponent to draw at that location
        gameObject.setX(x); 
        gameObject.setY(y);
        gameObjects.add(gameObject);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
        for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++){
            GameObject go = gameObjects.get(i);
            g.drawImage(go.getSprite(), go.getX(), go.getY(), this);
        }
    }
}
```

So lets say we create a room:

```
public class Room1 extends Room{
    public Room1(){
        this.createShip();
    }
    public void createShip(){
        Ship = new Ship();
        // Add an object to a list setting its x,y to 10,10
        this.addGameObjectAt(ship, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

**Note:** These objects are not added to the window with `addGameObjectAt` they are simply added to an `ArrayList` and then in the thread in Room are painted to the screen.

Now that we added `Ship` to the room it can be drawn on the screen using `paintComponent()`. This all works fine!

Here is where things start to stop working. Now that we have a `Ship` class added, I would like to add some key events, currently I have to add `Main` for them to work, but I don't want to add them there, because it gets messy, I would like to add them to `Ship`, since that is what the events will effect in the end.

This code doesn't attach the keylistener

```
// GameObject extends JPanel
public class Ship extends GameObject{
    public Ship(){
        this.addKeyListener(new AL());
    }

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
            System.out.println("here");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, pressing a key does not print out **here**, but if I move the `AL` class and the `addKeyListener()` to the `Game` class it works, but I don't want it in the `Game` class I want it in the `Ship` class.

```
// This class just sets up the size of the application window
// It also holds an int list of all the game rooms
public class Game extends JFrame{

}
```

I have been trying to figure this out for at least a week now, and I can't seem figure out how can I get this so that it works in the `Ship` class?

Comment: "..but if I move the AL class and the addKeyListener() to the Game class it works" Can you show us what you did in `Game` class? Also, why do you extending your `Main` class with `JFrame`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JPanel` is not a focusable component so cannot interact with `KeyEvents`.

In Swing, the preferred approach is to use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). You can map an Action to a KeyStroke even when a component doesn't have focus.

See this [example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Comment: This is the clean solution.

Comment: I currently have key binding, but they don't seem to work the way I want. I think KeyAdpter does work the way I want. I want to be able to press 2 keys at once and keyadpter isn't allowing me to do that.

Comment: With `KeyBindings` you can define a key with modifiers similar to a regular `KeyListener`. What 2 keys are you trying to combine?

Comment: @RyanNaddy: I second this advice (1+) -- go with key bindings. If it's not working as you'd like, tell us and show us more and we can help.

Comment: +1 I cant say how many times I've seen this problem. Keybindings are the ONLY choice for Swing components unless one loves buggy code.

Comment: Here are the problems I am having with KeyBindings: 1) When you hold down a key it moves once pauses then moves at a constant pace like holding down the space in a textbox. 2) I can not press two keys at once and have both keys fire at the same time, also don't want to program every possible 2 key combination that would be `4^3*4^2*4` or something like that number of combinations for just the arrow keys. But if I can get them to work seamlessly I would defiantly use them because I have them working now. Just not how I'd like.

Comment: @RyanNaddy if i understand correctly you should use flags of sorts, like booleans to flag when a key is pressed down or not than checking these booleans will allow you to see if 2 keys are pressed down at the same time (of course dont forget to reset the flags as needed) see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825515/java-rectangle-collision-detection-confusion/13827649#13827649

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the JPanel focusable. Try ship.setFocusable(true);

Comment: I added it to the ship class, and doesn't work. I then tried adding it to where the instance is created and still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to click your panel so that it gets the focus? If it then doesn't work, i'm sorry.

Comment: If it does work, you just have to make it the component that gets the focus first.