# Java Delayed/Inaccurate Collision Detection

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, collision-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java rectangle collision detection confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825515/java-rectangle-collision-detection-confusion)

I have run into a problem with collision detection, I have asked around other forums and been searching Google for a month now (No one had an answer). My problem with collision detection is that it's delayed or inaccurate, sometimes it detects it perfectly, sometimes halfway through and sometimes not at all. Some people say it's a synchronicity problem between my update loop (using swing timer)  and KeyInput. What do you think?

Code! :)

KeyInput:

```
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D && walkRight == true)
        {

                Screen.movementX=-1;


        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A && walkLeft == true)
        {

                Screen.movementX=1;



        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S && walkDown == true)
        {

                Screen.movementY=-1;



        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W && walkUp == true)
        {

                Screen.movementY=1;



        }





        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D && walkRight == false)
        {

                Screen.movementX =0;


        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A && walkLeft == false)
        {

                Screen.movementX=0;



        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S && walkDown == false)
        {

                Screen.movementY=0;



        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W && walkUp == false)
        {

                Screen.movementY=0;



        }






}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        Screen.movementX=0;
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        Screen.movementX=0;
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        Screen.movementY=0;
    }
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        Screen.movementY=0;
    }
}
```

Collision:

```
public static void collision()
{
    p.walkUp = true;
    p.walkDown = true;
    p.walkLeft = true;
    p.walkRight = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < wallTileArr.size(); i++)
    {
        wallTile = wallTileArr.get(i);
        wallTile.collision(p);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public void collision(Player p)
{
    if (p.downGetBounds().intersects(getBounds()))
    {
        p.walkDown = false;
    }

    else if (p.upGetBounds().intersects(getBounds()))
    {
        p.walkUp = false;
    }
    else if (p.leftGetBounds().intersects(getBounds()))
    {
        p.walkLeft = false;
    }
    else if (p.rightGetBounds().intersects(getBounds()))
    {
        p.walkRight = false;
    }

}
```

Switching JPanels (Using this for Main Menu etc)

```
public static void changePanelTo(Component add)
{
        Main.f.getContentPane().invalidate();
        Main.f.getContentPane().removeAll();
        Main.f.add(add);
        Main.f.validate();
        add.requestFocusInWindow();





}
```

Feel free to ask questions regarding the code!

Download: [Click Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?lz99e5n1vhcmish)

Comment: Can you provide a short, runnable example that displays the problems you are having?

Comment: Can u proved the code for update loop (using swing timer) ?

Comment: Is this occurring when only one key is pressed, or during a sequence of events?

Comment: Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

Comment: Download: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?lz99e5n1vhcmish

Comment: `Download: Click Here` --->  no thank you, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. described issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are using `java.util.Timer` class then watch **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)** . 
It Clearly stays that:

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. **Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to
>   complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in
>   turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up"
>   and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task
>   finally completes**.

So sometimes the TimerTask associated with your Timer class is fired on exact collision time but sometimes it takes a while because by that time your previous task might be completing..

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks! :). But what should I then use to run the loop?

Comment: I have just gone through your code vaguely and found that you have used javax.swing.Timer . In `actionPerformed` you have called the numbers of methods ..ranging from repaint() to CheckFPS()..update()...etc..etc.Moreover you have called Collision.collision() thrice over there..This taking a lot of time for completion per cycle of actionPerformed execution. For better concurrency in swing with longer task you should use `javax.swing.SwingWorker` API . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html .

Comment: And to know how to work with this API see here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html