# Moving a rectangle down a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to make a program to move rectangles down a JFrame, can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

```
public class DrawingComponent extends JLabel {

public static int x = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,x,50,50);
    g2.draw(rect);
    x = x+100;
}
}

public class GameL {

javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();

public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameL tetris = new GameL();
        tetris.start();     
}

public void start(){
    //setup frame
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    TimerEH timereh = new TimerEH();
    Timer timer = new Timer(5000,timereh);
    timer.start();          
}

class TimerEH implements ActionListener{        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        DrawingComponent dc = new DrawingComponent();
        frame.add(dc);
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `DrawingComponent` and adding it to the frame on each tick cycle.  That's a lot of `DrawComponent`s

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825515/java-rectangle-collision-detection-confusion/13827649#13827649) similar answer and its [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999506/threads-with-key-bindings/14001011#14001011). And [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d) final example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `DrawingComponent` and adding it to the frame on each tick cycle. That's a lot of `DrawComponent`s

While it is possible to animation a component by moving it, you would need to provide more information as to why you want to do it this way.  The preferred method would be to use something like a `JPanel`, add it the frame that's using a `BorderLayout` and override the panels `paintComponent` method.

The issue with trying "move" the component is components have a defined space in which they can render, from the looks of you code, you label is likely to have a size of 0x0, which isn't much space to paint in at all...

**Updated with example**

So, the following example demonstrates the painting of a rectangle WITHIN the confines of component by using a layout manager that will attempt to size the component to the available usable space.

It also shows the user `getPreferredSize` to provide useful size hints back to the layout manager.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CreppyRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CreppyRectangle();
    }

    public CreppyRectangle() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.RED));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.GREEN));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.BLUE));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.ORANGE));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.PINK));
                frame.add(new TestPane(Color.MAGENTA));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int yPos;
        private int size = 25 + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
        private int yDelta = 5 + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

        public TestPane(Color foreground) {
            setForeground(foreground);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yPos += yDelta;
                    if (yPos < 0) {
                        yPos = 0;
                        yDelta *= -1;
                        System.out.println(yDelta);
                    } else if (yPos + size > getHeight()) {
                        yPos = getHeight() - size;
                        yDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getForeground());
            g2d.drawRect(0, yPos, getWidth() - 1, size);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your detailed response! This community is amazing and i cant wait for the day i can contribute answers instead of questions. Thank You!